# How can I get each object from multiple arrays and put them all into one array

Tags: javascript, arrays, type-conversion, nested-object

Right now I have a list of objects.They are stored in a variable right now labeled listOfObjects. they are not comma seperated because I used the Object.entries method to get these values from a different array

```
console.log(listOfObjects)
outputs

{ q: 'LanceStephenson', tbm: 'isch' } 
{ q: 'GorguiDieng', tbm: 'isch' } 
{ q: 'SolomonHill', tbm: 'isch' }
```

(I want them to be in one array)

I would like for this to happen

```
console.log(listOfObjects)
outputs

[
{ q: 'LanceStephenson', tbm: 'isch' },
{ q: 'GorguiDieng', tbm: 'isch' },
{ q: 'SolomonHill', tbm: 'isch' }

]
Remember the listOfObjects is strictly a bunch of objects without commas, separating them. I want them to be an array
```

Comment: The first output is not a valid array or object. And all keys are the same. Currently it looks like three objects where logged.

Answer (score 1):

Use `[...listOfObjects]` to convert the list of objects to an array. Then you can use array methods like `.map()` to iterate over it. Then get the `[object Object]` property of each array element.

```js
const listOfObjects = [{
    '[object Object]': {
      q: 'LanceStephenson',
      tbm: 'isch'
    }
  },
  {
    '[object Object]': {
      q: 'GorguiDieng',
      tbm: 'isch'
    }
  },
  {
    '[object Object]': {
      q: 'SolomonHill',
      tbm: 'isch'
    }
  }
];

const newArrayOfObjects = [...listOfObjects].map(el => el['[object Object]']);
console.log(newArrayOfObjects);
```

Comment: when i try the listofObjects.map function it says listofObjects not a function because it is a list of objects and not array with objects in it. In your example the listofObjects is an array []

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have lists, so what do you mean by a list of objects? I assumed you meant array of objects.

Comment: i ran object.values on my json object to get  the object values I am looking to put in the final array. It looks like this.                               const obj = queryNames.qn.reduce((o, key) => Object.assign(o, {[key]: { q: value, tbm: 'isch' }}), {});  const listOfObjects =  Object.values(obj)                 This is how I got the 'listOfObjects' Javascript list

Comment: That's a single object. I don't see how you're getting the output you show in the question.

Comment: What is `value` in that code?

Comment: Why don't you just create the array you want in the first place, instead of creating this list of objects?

Comment: value returns LanceStephenson,GorguiDieng,SolomonHill

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246798/discussion-between-evan-and-barmar).